# Installing Samplicator on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, netflow

I'm trying to install Samplicator to test Netflow central collector and then forwarding to other collectors from there. I mainly want to use Samplicator due to it being able to easily sample the Netflow data and/or send the full raw feed.

When I download it from the github repo, there is no configure file by default like the install instructions say. I've tried using autoconf and various automake commands to get configure to show up and it does finally, but says

```
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'
```

Has anyone else had experience installing this software recently? I know it hasn't been updated in quite a while.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: I found a branch of the samplicator product called samplicator-debian that seems to have the configure file by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projects usually include a `bootstrap` script that generates the necessary GNU autoconf environment. These files aren't checked into git, so you'll need to run the script to generate them yourself.

Unfortunately this particular project includes no such script, so you'll have to do it yourself. These items need to be run to generate `configure` and its necessary friends:

```
aclocal
libtoolize
autoconf
automake
```

Depending on the program, they may also need various options passed to them. Contact the program author if you have trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to contact them and get the specific parameters. I was just making sure I didn't overlook something since all of the install instructions say nothing about it and already have the configure file there.